# BAT How to open dialog directory in BAT for set JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, batch-file

I wouldlike to write a script where users can choose the path of `JAVA_HOME`

How can I do that ?

I start with this :

```
@ECHO OFF

SETX JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6" 
SETX PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"

echo Variable JAVA HOME configure : %JAVA_HOME%
echo Variable PATH configure : %PATH%
```

But now I wouldlike to remplace the actual value of JAVA_HOME by choose directory ?

Comment: Sorry, but you have corrupted __user__ environment variable `PATH` with the third command line which you need to manually fix now. The commands to use are `set "JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-11.0.6"` and `set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"`.

Comment: Just to expand upon the above comment, the `%PATH%` variable, is not like others. It is special in that it contains the joined content of both the System `%PATH%` and the User `%PATH%`. Your code, with no `/M` option, is effectively adding the current content of the System `%PATH%` variable, and the current content of the User `%PATH%` variable, and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin` to the User `%PATH%` variable content, which means that youre creating multiple duplicated entries.